# Разница в скобках?

Tags: javascript

```js
let user = {
  name: "Вася",
  start() {
  alert(this.name) 
  }
};

user.start(); // Здесь нет скобок.



let user = {
  name: "Коля",
  start() { 
  alert(this.name) 
  }
};

(user.start)();  // А здесь user.start в скобках, зачем они?
```

Comment: низачем *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Получается скобки это ошибка?

Comment: Нет, скобки задают приоритет, но в данном случае они ни на что не влияют.

Comment: Скобки это оператор группировки?

Comment: Да. Скобки могут выступать в роли оператора группировки или в роли оператора вызова функции. Здесь левые скобки являются оператором группировки, а правые оператором вызова функции. Если раскрыть оператор группировки, то вы получите первый вариант `user.start( )`. Следовательно никакой разницы.

Answer (score 1):

Тут это не имеет значения.
Ну, если уж на то пошло, то вот пара примеров, когда имеет.

```js
function foo() {
    return 0;
}

function boo() {
    return "boo";
}

console.log((foo && boo)()); // boo
console.log(foo() && boo()); // 0


console.log((foo || boo)()); // 0 
console.log((foo() || boo())); // boo
```

Когда вы используете `foo` и `boo` без скобочек, вы оперируете функциями как обьктами, однако вызывая `foo()` и `boo()` вы начинаете оперировать результатом выполнения этих функций.

Comment: Что такое скобки? Это оператор группировки?

Comment: Да, да, это он.

Comment: Просто приоритет у функций больше, чем приоритет у остальных операций, так что в данном случае результат разный.